# Finding the limit of $\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\to 0} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k\varepsilon^2}{d^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I want to find the limit $\varepsilon \to 0$ of a certain series:
$$\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\to 0} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k\varepsilon^2}{d^2}.$$
Here $d>0$ is a constant and $\varepsilon >0$.

I suppose that it tends to 0, but I am not sure how to show it. Am I even allowed to exchange limit and sum?
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k\varepsilon^2}{d^2}$ diverges (unless $\varepsilon=0$)?

Comment: Did you mean to have the upper limit on the sum as $1/\epsilon$ for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k\varepsilon^2}{d^2}=\frac{\varepsilon^2}{d^2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty k=\infty$$

(in the sense that the series diverges to $\infty$) for all $\varepsilon>0$, so the same holds when we let $\varepsilon\to0$, i.e.

$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k\varepsilon^2}{d^2}=\infty$$

in the sense that it diverges to $\infty$.

Comment: Oh, I see.. my question was kind of stupid, i should have seen that. Thank you so much!